# Flex/Air datagrid open ContextMenu using mouseDown rather than rightMouseDown?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4

In a Flex 4/Air app, I've got an itemrenderer in a column of a Datagrid. I'd like the item to open the ContextMenu on itemRenderer.mouseDown but it seems to only work with itemRenderer.rightMouseDown. Any ideas as to why? and/or a good workaround?

thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, a class can force a contextmenu to open by calling contextMenu.display(stage, x, y);

Answer (score 0):

I like to call it UI Precedent.

Why do you want to change the common convention that users have already been trained to learn?

Comment: Perhaps PC users are used to using right-click context menus but most Mac users aren't. So in this case by adding a button in the datagrid that opens the ContextMenu menu we're making it easier to find the additional functionality...now I just need to figure out where/why the event action is being suppressed ;)

Comment: On a Mac, I would expect the Flash player to bring up the context menu using the same "OS Standard" that Mac uses.  Are you saying this is not happening?  How do Mac users bring up the context menu?

Comment: nah, it works on Mac. The point I was making is that from a usability perspective Mac users don't use right-click nearly as often. The issue I was having is that the contextmenu wasn't displaying when being set from a normal mousedown event, but problem solved. thnx for chiming in though!